# Retrieve id from stored procedure to call nested procedure - PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I need to call a first procedure (CrushProps) and then loop through each row by calling a second procedure (CrushOutcomes) with a value (PropId) from the row in the results from the first (and return all rows from the new procedure).

I have looked at this question but cannot make it work for me:
[calling nested stored procedure from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960672/calling-nested-stored-procedure-from-php?newreg=caff0e862d7f45ee87d3a7365a363fe4)

These are the two stored procedures:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CrushProps $$
create procedure CrushProps(IN crID int)
begin

select props.PropText, props.Prop_Id 
from props inner join crush_props on props.Prop_Id = crush_props.PropId
where crush_props.CrushId = crID;
end $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CrushOutcomes $$
create procedure CrushOutcomes(IN prID int)
begin

select prop_outcomes.OutcomeText, prop_outcomes.OutcomePoints  
from prop_outcomes inner join crush_props ON prop_outcomes.PropId = crush_props.PropId
WHERE prop_outcomes.PropId = prID;

end $$
```

Being new to PHP and MySQL I have tried many different variations without any luck. The code below runs thru the two procedures sequentially and returns all rows from the first but only one row from the second (and AFTER the full result - not after each row).

I cannot figure out how to make it loop thru each row of the first procedure.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"CALL CrushProps('$crushid')") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());

if($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
   $prptxt = $row[PropText];
   $prpid = $row[Prop_Id];

    echo $prptxt . "<br/>"; 
    }

            $result->close();
            $con->next_result();
}


$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"CALL CrushOutcomes('$prpid')") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());

if($result2->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
   $outtxt = $row2[OutcomeText];
   $outpts = $row[OutcomePoints];

    echo $outtxt . "<br/>"; 

    }
}
```

Comment: How many rows are returned from the second procedure?

Comment: Since your 2nd `mysqli_query()` is after/outside your 1st `mysqli_query()` it will only call the last value of `$prpid`. If you want it to do all `$prpid` values, you need to nest it inside the loop of the 1st.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I get four rows which is the number of rows per $prpid. So the output is correct but I only get it from one row from the first procedure. But I see there is a small error in Row/Row2 but this is not related to my problem.

Comment: @Sean Yes, I believe that's right but I have not been able to achieve this without getting "Commands out of sync" or other error.

Comment: Alternately, you could save the `$prpid` to an array, and then loop over that array to do the 2nd query.

Comment: @Sean Do you have an example of how that would look?

Comment: Instead of `$prpid = $row[Prop_Id];` you would do something like `$prpids[] = $row[Prop_Id];`. Then you would do `foreach($prpids as $prpid){ $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"CALL CrushOutcomes('$prpid')" ...[rest of your code]...}`

Comment: @Sean Thanks. I get the following error: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in..." on the line "    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))" in the second query. Any thoughts?

Comment: That error tells you that `$result2` is not a `mysqli_result` but either a `true`/`false`(boolean). Typically that means that the query failed. You need to find out why the query in `$result2` failed. Also, `mysqli_error()` requires the connection, so it should be `...or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($con));`. That might help you find the query error message.

Comment: I just noticed that the closing `)` for `mysqli_query()` is missing in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163964/retrieve-id-from-stored-procedure-to-call-nested-procedure-php-and-mysql#comment56077998_34163964), so hopefully you did not copy/paste that example exactly.

Comment: @Sean I got that, thanks.. But it still doesn't work. I added echo $prpid right after echo $prptxt after the first query to check the output and it comes out prptxt1, prptxt2, prpid1, prptxt3, prpid2, prptxt4, prpid3, etc. So that means that the first $prpid in the second query is empty and that probably throws the error. But why is $prpid offset?